# How to interpolate an int into a string with F#?

Tags: .net, f#, typing

I'm trying what should be a really basic example application, but this particular example from MS's [F# intro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/fsharp-first-program/5-exercise-operators) produces this warning in intellisense:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    ''a -> int'    
but given a
    ''a -> unit'    
The type 'int' does not match the type 'uint'F# Compiler1
```

from this code: (fwiw I have tried both implicit and explicit typing for *sum*)

```ml
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Welcome to the calculator program"
    printfn "Type the first number"
    let firstNo = Console.ReadLine()
    printfn "Type the second number"
    let secondNo = Console.ReadLine()
    printfn "First %s, Second %s" firstNo secondNo
    let sum: int = 0
    printfn "The sum is %i" sum
```

Then when I compile I get this error, as expected, based off the warning:

```sh
error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a↔    ''a -> int'    ↔but given a↔    ''a -> unit'    ↔The type 'int' does not match the type 'unit' [C:\Users\user-name\source\repos\MyFSharpApp\MyFSharpApp.fsproj]
```

Being new to F# I'm not sure why the printfn function thinks an int is a unit and breaking compilation. Could really use an explanation and/or link(s) to doc(s) of why this is the case and how to resolve it.

---

#### Edit

So an interesting point, even when I remove the interpolation all together and just print a string, I get the same error. So no int at all, but the string expects an int instead of a unit...but, why? I'm guessing I have some sort of syntax error, regardless this seems quite weird.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, remove the zero from the very end of `main` as you were adding the code from the exercises?

Comment: `main` function is expected to return an `int` (0 meaning success), hence the given signature `'a -> int`. Just add a line with just `0` at the end of the function (currently returning `unit`).

Comment: @FyodorSoikin and Romain Deneau, you are both correct, the zero is missing. The tutorial doesn't show the zero and I imagine I copied over it or deleted without realizing. If one of you want to put in an answer explaining why that's needed with examples I think that'd help other newbies who make that simple mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` function is supposed to return an `int`, which will become the program execution result. The convention is: zero for success, non-zero to signify an error code (this is not F#-specific).

When you create a new project with `dotnet new`, as the exercises direct, the `main` function is generated returning a zero.

But as you have confirmed in the comments, your `main` function does not currently have a zero, which probably means that you have deleted it accidentally.

Just add the zero back in and the error will go away.

---

In the shiny new .NET 6, the default generator generates [an implicit entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/entry-point) instead of the good ol' `main` function, in which case the return value is not required, and if you do want to return one, you have to use the `exit` function.

However, this clearly does not apply to the current question, since the OP's generator generated a `main` function, not implicit entry point.

Comment: No, if you do `dotnet new console -lang F#`, you no longer get the old template with an explicit entry point, but it is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/entry-point). So if you could just refer to explicit entry point instead of template, that'd be good.

Comment: Not entirely true @BrentTranberg. On my installation (of .NET 5) it does generate a `main` function, and so it does for OP, judging by their question. I added a bit of clarification to the answer though.

Comment: Thanks for adding the clarification edit. A jsuk, I copied the main function from the tutorial as the template gave me nothing more than a single `printfn` since I'm running VS 2022 + .NET 6